# problem with condition IF in google javascript

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to do research if the value of one cell is present in another sheet.
I retrieve the value of the searched cell then browse all the rows of my sheet2.
I can display the values, but my IF condition is not working. It is never taken into account.

```
club=feuilleClub.getRange(j,1).getValues();
clubComp=feuilleLic.getRange(i,5).getValues();
 if (club == clubComp) {
      Browser.msgBox("Find");
     feuilleLic.getRange(i, 10).setValue(clubNom); 

    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getValues()` instead of `getValue()`. The `getValues()` method will return a two dimensional array hence, the comparison is not accurate.

You should update your code to this:

```
club=feuilleClub.getRange(j,1).getValue();
clubComp=feuilleLic.getRange(i,5).getValue();
```

#### Reference

- [Class Range Apps Script
  getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Class Range Apps Script
  getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

Comment: If this was of help to you, kindly mark the answer as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) @KostiaBoudine